# ClearCase permission on single directory

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to make one folder in our VOB where it is readable by everyone, but only one group can write to it.  This is what I have done, but I am starting to think that I missed something...

1. I had a new windows group created and added the specific users to it.
2. I added this group to the vob group list. (Does it have to be added to the PVOB as well?)
3. I changed "group" owner on the folder to this group.
4. I added this group to my CLEARCASE_GROUPS environment variable (and restarted.)

I am still getting "permission denied" when I update, and I am not able to add any files under the folder.  Did I in fact miss a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to:

- add this group to your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`
- then create a dynamic view (it will be protected with this group)
- then mount this vob
- and try to create a folder in it.

See also "[How to restrict VOB read access in ClearCase (Windows Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/966021/6309)" for a concrete example.

I mention a dynamic view because it will be easier/faster to test the Vob access and folder creation with it. Once it is working, create a snapshot view in the same conditions and it should also work.

Note: if this Vob is an [UCM component Vob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9579131/6309), I would recommend adding that group at least to the secondary groups of its associated pvob.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working now.  However, could you explain why the group needs to be in CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP and not CLEARCASE_GROUPS?  I normally have my default group in the primary.

Comment: `CLEARCASE_GROUPS` is used in conjunction with `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297283/error-while-updating-clearcase-snapshot-view